# BlockUI - TypeError: $.blockUI is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, blockui, jquery-blockui

I'm using jquery blockUI to trigger loading screens. I've used the same script on two other .aspx pages and it worked just fine. However, I added this to my current .aspx page and Firefox/Chrome Console is saying $.blockUI is not a function.

I've already tried changing it to $.fn.blockUI and received the same error. I know there are other similar topics, but I've tried some of those solutions with the same results.

Here is my current aspx page script:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
    type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#<%= Submit1.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            $.blockUI({ message: $('#loader') });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is a different aspx page where it works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
    type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#<%= generateView.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            $.blockUI({ message: $('#loader') });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the #loader  that is used by both scripts:

```
<div id="loader" style="display:none">
    <img src="Icon/octo.gif"/><h1>Loading...</h1>
</div>
```

Both scripts are triggered by an asp:Button click, the only obvious differences I see are the Name.ClientID.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide online link where this error can be checked. Maybe you are overwritting jQuery/$ by including it twice later after including blockUI plugin

Comment: What do you mean by online link? The error only references to my .aspx mark up that I posted. As far as the script src goes, this has been used twice on two separate pages. I tried removing one of the jquery.min.us src links but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @A.Wolff I see what you mean by online link actually. However, this TypeError didn't reference the only src links.